# mod_rewrite on localhost won't work for clean url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite `localhost/site/1` into `localhost/site/index.php?id=1` but that doesn't work! I receive a 404 error. mod_rewrite is enabled and other rewrite rules work but im biting my teeth out on that one. My rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^localhost/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ localhost/$1/index.php?id=$2
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to include the domain, as the rules are looking for `localhost/localhost/`.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?id=$2
```

Comment: dude i love you thanks for helping a noob out. appreciate it!

Comment: yes sorry i couldnt do it when ive read your answer so i had to wait ind kinda forgot it :)